# Connect to adobe stratus server in a flex application from inside a proxy

Tags: apache-flex, flash, proxy, adobe

I am trying to develop a P2P conferencing application in flex using RTMFP. So I have to make connection to Adobe Stratus server for Id of Flash Player instance. I am a student and behind the http proxy. I have checked in NetConnection class but, didn't find anything related proxy configuration.So, How can I configure proxy settings for my flex application.

Thanks,
GG

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some info about proxy 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/rtmfp_stratus_app.html